# How to use max_pooling indices to subsample/pool another tensor of the same size in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

How can I use the indices obtained from max_pooling a tensor with to subsample or pool another tensor of the same size?

Here is my attempt:

```
import torch

# -- assuming y1 and e1 have the same dimensions
y1 = torch.randn(1, 32, 28, 28)
e1 = torch.randn(1, 32, 28, 28)

# -- max-pooling
mxp = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2, return_indices=True)
y1_pooled, idx = mxp(y1)

# -- subsample e1 using idx
e1 = e1[idx]
```

But I get

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     e1 = e1[idx]
> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 1
> ```